# can't pass the tor and privoxy page test on CentOS7

Tags: proxy, web-crawler, tor

I have successfully started the tor and privoxy. But when I came to the page test, it always said that "Privoxy is not being used"  .

I followed the answer of Question 4.10 "**How do I use Privoxy together with Tor?**" on this [page](http://www.privoxy.org/faq/misc.html#TOR)  ,but failed.

I'm working on CentOS7 and used  **Wget** to get the test page http://config.privoxy.org/show-status .

Any help would be really appreciated!

**this is what I type in command line:**

```
(myapp)[hadoop@kaiyuandao myapp]$ sudo service privoxy start
/etc/init.d/privoxy: line 97: kill: (24849) - No such process
Starting Privoxy, OK.
(myapp)[hadoop@kaiyuandao myapp]$ sudo service tor start
Starting tor...done.
(myapp)[hadoop@kaiyuandao myapp]$ wget http://config.privoxy.org/show-status
--2015-09-08 05:43:08--  http://config.privoxy.org/show-status
Resolving config.privoxy.org (config.privoxy.org)... 198.199.92.59, 162.243.226.87
Connecting to config.privoxy.org (config.privoxy.org)|198.199.92.59|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://privoxy.org/config/show-status [following]
--2015-09-08 05:43:08--  http://privoxy.org/config/show-status
Resolving privoxy.org (privoxy.org)... 216.34.181.97
Connecting to privoxy.org (privoxy.org)|216.34.181.97|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://www.privoxy.org/config/ [following]
--2015-09-08 05:43:09--  http://www.privoxy.org/config/
Resolving www.privoxy.org (www.privoxy.org)... 216.34.181.97
Reusing existing connection to privoxy.org:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3832 (3.7K) [text/html]
Saving to: ?.how-status.1?

100%[=======================================================================================================>] 3,832       --.-K/s   in 0s      

2015-09-08 05:43:09 (82.2 MB/s) - ?.how-status.1?.saved [3832/3832]

(myapp)[hadoop@kaiyuandao myapp]$ vi show-status
```

**and this is the content I get from the test page**

```
Privoxy is not being used

The fact that you are reading this page shows that Privoxy was not used in the process of accessing it. Had the request been made through Privoxy, it would have been intercepted and you would be looking at Privoxy's web-based user interface now.

So what went wrong? Chances are (in this order) that:

this page is in your browser's cache. You've once been here before starting to use Privoxy, and now your browser thinks that it already knows the content of this page. Hence it doesn't request a fresh copy.

Force your browser to do that. With most browsers, clicking "reload" while holding down the shift key (shift-reloading) should suffice, but you might need to manually clear the browser's cache (both memory and disk cache).

your browser is not set up to use Privoxy.

Check your browser's proxy settings and make sure that it uses 127.0.0.1, port 8118 (or, if you did a custom configuration, whatever different values you used).

when using multiple proxies in a chain, that either the chain is broken at some point before Privoxy, or that an earlier proxy serves this page from its cache.

Shift-reload, clear all caches, and if the problem still persists, trace the proxy chain starting with your browser's settings. Please refer to the forwarding chapter of the user manual for details.

Until version 2.9.13, Privoxy was also known as Internet Junkbuster. If you recently upgraded, then the web-based interface has moved - it is now at http://config.privoxy.org/ (Short form: p.p [Privoxy Proxy]).

If you have read the user manual and still have trouble, feel free to submit a support request to get help.
```

Comment: Have you tested Privoxy without Tor? Does it work?

Comment: @Rejected I killed the tor process,and restart privoxy, but got the same test result as before

Comment: You said you followed the instructions in your link.  The first line is literally "Before you configure Privoxy to use Tor, please follow the User Manual chapters 2. Installation and 5. Startup to make sure Privoxy itself is setup correctly."  You haven't done this.  Go back, and follow the instructions.

Comment: @Rejected thanks a lot! I rechecked my startup steps and find that I didn't set the http proxy to 127.0.0.1:8118.

Answer (score 0):

My main problem is that I forgot to set the http proxy.

Since I use **wget** to get pages, I changed **/etc/wgetrc** and set **http_proxy=127.0.0.1** .

FYI